# How to group common data members/variables in c?

Tags: c, header, include

I am writing a code in C which has the following basic structure:

Part A: Starting/Init of the main module, calling of various sub-modules and final compliation of the results from the sub-modules.

Part B: Actual execution of the sub-modules.

```
Now, part A has its own main.c and main.h file
Part B has three modules: 
sub1.c/sub1.h
sub2.c/sub2.h
sub3.c/sub3.h
```

There are a lot of common variables and functions that are used in the sub-modules.
I would like to have a common module which could be #included in all the sub-modules and all the common functions/variables be used. (common.c and common.h)

Now, for the common functions, I can declare them in common.h and then define in common.c and then they could directly be used in all the sub-modules.
But there are a lot of common data variables/members also which i want to 'common' out.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this, so that i could directly use them in all the sub-modules?

In c++, it could just be added to common.h and then could be used with any file  that includes common.h but i believe that it is a little different in c. 
Could someone please help explain the difference?

thanks

Comment: If you have lots of variables shared between multiple modules, then you probably have a design problem.  Find a way to avoid sharing variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In C or C++:**

Should go in a `.h`:

```
// declaration, means it's defined somewhere else
// can declare it as many times as you want
extern int yourVariable;
```

Every object (as in the intermediate file generated during the compilation process for a `.c` or `.cpp` file, not an object in OOP) that wants to use a variable needs to know about it (thus have a definition somewhere).

Should go in a `.c`/`.cpp`:

```
int yourVariable = 3; // definition, should only define it once
int yourVariable2; // also a definition
```

The `extern` keyword is optional for functions.

```
int square(int num); // function declaration (.h)
extern int square(int num); // same as above
int square(int num) { return num*num; } // function definition (.c)
```

**In C++:**

Should go in a `.h`:

```
// this is a declaration
class yourClass
{
  int yourVariable;
}
```

Should go in a `.cpp`:

```
int yourClass::yourVariable = 3;
```

I could be wrong, but I'm not aware of difference between C and C++ in this regard (except that C++ has classes).

Comment: Thanks. one add on question. I want to have the same value of the variable in all  the modules. Eg: errrocode, if one of the module changes it to -12, others should also be able to see it as -12. How would that be possible?

Comment: Just use `extern int errorCode;` in a common `.h` and `int errorCode;` in any `.c`/`.cpp` file.